# How do I insert data into Django models with foreign key tables and OneToOne fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

"Hello everyone, I hope you're doing well. I'm currently facing an issue with inserting data in models with foreign key table and OneToOne field. I've tried inserting data in, but I haven't been able to find a success. It would be great if someone could help me out or provide some guidance on how to resolve this. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!"

**MODELS:**

```
class Department(models.Model):
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.department
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['department']

class StudentID(models.Model):
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.student_id
    
class Student(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, related_name='depart', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_id = models.OneToOneField(StudentID, related_name='studentId', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    student_email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    student_age = models.IntegerField(default=18)
    student_address = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.student_name
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['student_name']
        verbose_name  = 'student'
    

class Subject(models.Model):
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.subject_name


class SubjectMark(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='studentmark', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    marks = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f' {self.student.student_name} {self.subject.subject_name} '

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['student' , 'subject']
```

I've tried this view but I got only errors.

**Views**

```
def create_student(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.POST
        student_id = data.get('student_id')
        student_name = data.get('student_name')
        department = data.get('department')
        student_email = data.get('student_email')
        student_address = data.get('student_address')
        student_age = data.get('student_age')
        marks = data.get('marks')
        subject = data.get('subject')

        Student.objects.create(
            student__student_id = student_id,
            student__department = department,
            student__student_name = student_name,
            student__student_email = student_email,
            student__student_age = student_age,
            student__student_address = student_address,
            marks = marks,
            subject__subject_name = subject
        )
    
        return redirect('/student/')
    context = {'page' : "Add Student"}
    
    return render(request, 'report/add_student.html', context)
```

If anybody can solve it plase make sure it post view method with it how to insert data from UI.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a database row with fields that don't exist on the `Student` model. Take a look at your model definition:

```py
class Student:
    department = ...
    student_id = ...
    student_name = ...
    student_email = ...
    student_age = ...
    student_address = ...
```

Now take a look at what you are passing in to `Student.objects.create()`:

```py
student__student_id = ...
student__department = ...
student__student_name = ...
student__student_email = ...
student__student_age = ...
student__student_address = ...
marks = ...
subject__subject_name = ...
```

Notice that each argument is prefixed by `student__`, so it looks for those fields (`student__student_id`, etc.), which don't exist. You need to delete the `student__` prefix.

Furthermore `student_id` and `department` are not primitive fields, they are foreign keys. Before you can define the relation on the `Student` object for a `StudentID` object, the `StudentID` object has to exist. Same with `Deparment`. So create them first then pass them in:

```py
department = Department.objects.create(department="Computer Science")
student_id = StudentID.objects.create(student_id="100")

student = Student.objects.create(
    student_id=student_id,
    department=department,
    ...
)
```

Lastly, `marks` and `subject` do not exist on the `Student` model. You must create those separately, like in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

try this , i hope it helps

```
def create_student(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = data(request.POST)
        if data.is_valid():
            student_id = data.validated_data.get('student_id')
            student_name = data.validated_data.get('student_name')
            department = data.validated_data.get('department')
            student_email = data.validated_data.get('student_email')
            student_address = data.validated_data.get('student_address')
            student_age = data.validated_data.get('student_age')
            marks = data.validated_data.get('marks')
            subject = data.validated_data.get('subject')
            
            # getting the department
            try:
                student_department = Department.objects.get( department = department )
            except Department.DoesNotExist:
                return False
            
            # getting the student ID 
            try:
                student_ID = StudentID.objects.get( student_id = student_id )
            except StudentID.DoesNotExist:
                return False
            

            # storing the student record 
            student = Student()      
            student.department = student_department
            student.student_name = student_name
            student.student_email = student_email
            student.student_age = student_age
            student.student_address = student_address
            student.save()
            student.student_id.add( student_ID )

            # storing the subject
            student_subject = Subject() 
            student_subject.subject_name = subject
            student_subject.save()
            
            # storing the students marks which includes the
            #the student details , subjects and subjects marks
            student_subject_mark = SubjectMark()
            student_subject_mark.student = student #which is referring to the student profile created above
            student_subject_mark.subject = student_subject #which is student_subject profile created 
            student_subject_mark.marks = marks
        

            return redirect('/student/')
    context = {'page' : "Add Student"}
    
    return render(request, 'report/add_student.html', context)
```